# React Native: A problem occurred evaluating script when trying to run on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react native app and when I try to run it on my android device i get the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOXJz.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqy19.png)
When i run command 'react-native doctor'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB72C.png)

How do I fix this error?